# LPK.dll missing from computer

Tags: windows-7, dll

I cant open anything from my desktop or download anything from the web I keep getting error:

> LPK.dll is missing from your computer

What can I do?

Comment: Apparently, it's part of the Language Pack feature on Windows 7. See [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52da31c7-8726-4904-8dbd-c3de3747a0ec/lpkdll-is-missing-from-your-computer) for possible ways to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open a `cmd.exe` [as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run [sfc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) to detect and repair missing files.

```
sfc /scannow
```

[image]